# Scaling a stateful service which has primary/secondary architecture by setting a property

Tags: java, mongodb, kubernetes

I have a java web stateful service which connects to mongodb and currently it is being deployed as a jar directly on the VM. This service has a property in properties file i.e. `primary`.

If we set `primary` to true then it is primary instance of the application and on this instance mongodb aggregation will happen.

If we set `primary` to false then it is secondary instance of the application and on this instance no mongodb aggregation will happen but it will serve all read and write queries.

Now we are migrating towards k8s deployment.

Challenges are :

**How do we set the value of primary during the k8s pod deployment having multiple replicas ?**

**How do we handle the failure of primary instance of application pod ?**

I am open for any architectural changes suggestions in order to facilitate better deployment structure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **primary** and **secondary** you can pass the **environment** variables to POD and based on that POD will start with the respective configuration.

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                              envName,
                              env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

You can create the TWO different deployment into K8s one for the Primary and second for secondary.

> How do we set the value of primary during the k8s pod deployment
> having multiple replicas ?

You can set the environment variable which will be the same across all replicas of Primary and different environment variables for secondary.

> How do we handle the failure of primary instance of application pod ?

You can use the **readiness** and **liveness** probe to deployment so if any failure occurs K8s will auto restart the POD.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

If you can create the two deployment in K8s

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: deployment
metadata:
  name: primary
  labels:
    purpose: primary
spec:
  containers:
  - name: primary
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: primary
      value: "True"
```

Second deployment environment variables will goes like

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: deployment
metadata:
  name: secondary
  labels:
    purpose: secondary
spec:
  containers:
  - name: secondary
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: secondary
      value: "False"
```

If you are using the stateful set you can also configure same in it if not using the deployment.

Comment: My second question was more regarding in case of complete failure of primary, how would we make one of the secondary instance primary. I guess this is possible with leader election algorithms.